# Swift - async/await - Execute async method on background thread from MainActor Task

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

Here's my `viewDidLoad` method :

```swift
func viewDidLoad() {
    // Stuff here
    Task { @MainActor in 
        doSomeWorkOnMainThread1()
        doSomeWorkOnMainThread2()

        await doSomeBackgroundWork()

        doSomeWorkOnMainThread3()
        doSomeWorkOnMainThread4()
    }
}
```

And here's my method that should execute work on a background thread :

```swift
func doSomeBackgroundWork() async {
    // can add some code here
    // long image processing task
    assert(!Thread.isMainThread)
    // can add some code here
}
```

Is it possible to execute `doSomeBackgroundWork` on a background thread (without using GCD), and wait for it before going back to the main thread ?

Comment: "I would like" is a desire, not a question (and a rather vague desire). What's the actual question / problem? You've mapped out the code, so what's the issue with it? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I would recommend not using `@MainActor` like that. The way to be sure that a method runs on the main actor is to mark that method as `@MainActor`.

Comment: Thanks I've edited my question *

Comment: @matt If I add @MainActor to the method, I get this error : `'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency`

Comment: Well, that would be a separate question. :) But my point is, I don't think you can so easily guarantee that when you return from the background work you will still be on the main thread, unless `doSomeWorkOnMainThread3` is itself a main actor method. Of course I could be wrong, but that's my experience.

Comment: Try with a detached task.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solution is working, but it's not perfect I guess :

```
func doSomeBackgroundWork() async {
    await Task {
        // long image processing task
        assert(!Thread.isMainThread)
    }.result
}
```

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't _guarantee_ background execution unless it's an Actor method, as I already told you.

Comment: Where did you see that a defaullt `Task` can be run on the main thread? Is it written somewhere in official documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Task.sleep. Note that it is in nanoseconds which is Really Weird, so I have written an extension to switch to seconds; to get it, you must use a Double, not an Int:

```
extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {
    static func sleep(_ seconds:Double) async {
        await self.sleep(UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))
    }
    static func sleepThrowing(_ seconds:Double) async throws {
        try await self.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))
    }
}
```

The way to guarantee that a piece of work will be done on a background thread is to give that work to an Actor. That is what an Actor is for (in part).

So for example if an Actor has a method `doSleep` that calls `Task.sleep`, then if you instantiate that actor and call that method from your Task, it will sleep on a background thread.

Comment: My bad if it was not clear, `sleep` is just an example, I'm not actually doing sleep on a background thread, I'm doing actual work that takes time.

Comment: Then what's the problem. Just do the actual work that takes time. It should be an async method so you can call it with await.

Comment: It's gonna be executed on the main thread since it's called from a `@MainActor`, even with the `async` keyword

Comment: Not if it's an Actor method it won't. But again, this is why I say don't say `@MainActor in`.

Comment: Even with a @MainActor at the method level, the `async` is executed on the main thread, on my side at least.

Comment: I don't know what _you_ are doing. I've told you what _to_ do. What more do you need?

Comment: I've tried everything you told me and it doesn't work on my side. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong. Can you please post the solution ? I've removed the "sleep" part and edited my question, if that's more clear

Comment: Did you read my article on this topic? It might help: https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-5-replacing-gcd-with-async-await/

Comment: @Rob Actually I don't know. What change did they make in this? And in what version of Xcode did they make?

Comment: @Rob Okay, but they still didn't introduce a version that _isn't_ nanoseconds, which is what my extension provides.

Comment: I agree that an extension that provides a seconds-based rendition is useful. My point was merely that your non-throwing rendition is calling a deprecated method, and should probably be removed/fixed. (Personally, I’d just eliminate the non-throwing rendition and rename the throwing one, but that’s up to you.)

Comment: @Rob I think you're misunderstanding the deprecation. The method itself (nonthrowing) is not deprecated. What's happened is that the _name_ has changed to include the `nanoseconds:` label. There is still a nonthrowing and a throwing variant.

Comment: I don't want to belabor the point, but I do not believe that is correct. Try `sleep(nanoseconds:)` without `try` and you will receive an error “Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled”. E.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmqPA.png. I have looked at both the documentation and the headers, and I do not see a non-deprecated, non-throwing rendition. Perhaps you could show us how you are invoking a non-throwing rendition (other than, of course, invoking the throwing version with `try?`, which is cancellable but will discard the error if the task is canceled).